Go templ remove comments from result html
Is it possible to have templ remove HTML comments from the generated output _templ.go files?
I have not managed to find any info about this in the guide or command line help.
Manual: https://templ.guide/
Help: $ templ generate --help
Thank you very much in advance!
Note: there is no templ tag available in SO yet and I don't have enough reputation to create one.

blind guessing how this tool could be implemented: outside of templ ... blocks, you should be able to write regular go comments, inside templ ... blocks I would try: { /* this is a comment */ } (<- a go template comment ?)

@LeGEC Not exactly what I was after but interesting even so!
